# Jmeter I keep getting: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect'?

Tags: java, http, networking, jmeter

**Jmeter I keep getting: 'java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect' ?**

1. I have created a load test which tests a specific url at 200 users
2. when running the load test for x1 iteration i keep seem to be getting: Connection timed outs?
3. I have made the following changes listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560610(v=bts.20).aspx

But the issue is still there:
[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyQRh.png)

[image]

Comment: could you please specify how is your KeepAlive set on your proxy server. Or just show us Response headers from previuos sampler result. I expect that therte should be something like this:
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive

Comment: Most probably your server is slow at accepting connections. This is in fact one of the things you are testing. So you've found the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably don't have access to the target host from where you test.

Did you configure proxy as your web browser is probably configured

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server

But if failure is partial, then you server might be overloaded and rejecting some requests.

Comment: thanks for the comment, do you think this will still be the case even if some of the requests pass? for example out of 200http requests to the same url, 5 would fail

Comment: if only 5 of 200 fail but are for a different host, then it os possible. Otherwis it would be another cause. If answer is ok, please accept it and upvote so that it helps others

Comment: Hi, any feedback on answer? if ok it should be accepted and upvoted so that it's helpful to others

Comment: hi @UBIK LOAD PACK we are going to look into the root issue soon and then i will update the post, thanks

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that "problematic" requests are simply not able to finish in 20 seconds (most probably you have modified Connect timeout and set this value in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) or [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults))

20 seconds looks like a long response time to me so your finding indicates application under test performance problem.

Going forward if you would like to see more "human readable" message in the results file switch to [Duration Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Duration_Assertion) instead of setting timeouts on protocol level

[image: JMeter Duration Assertion]

See [How to Use JMeter Assertions in Three Easy Steps](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-assertions-3-easy-steps) article for more information on conditionally failing JMeter requests.

Comment: No. It isn't a response-time issue. It is a `ConnectException`, which happens at the connect phase. Read the question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check client configuration from where you are running your tests. It might be like your client system is not able to handle 200 threads. Do the test iteration wise means try with 10, 50 , 70 and so on. Check from which iteration onwards you are getting the error. It is also advisable not to include the listeners during load testing.

Please check the best practices for load testing using jmeter.
http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html